# jQuery scrolling DIV: stop scrolling when DIV reaches footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `#sidebar` (which starts below my `#header` div) and a `#footer` (around 120px off the bottom of the page).

I'm trying to make the sidebar scroll with the content of the page. The code below does this semi-successfully:

```
/* profile sidebar */
#sidebar>div{ width: 300px; margin-top: 10px; }
#sidebar.fixed>div{position:fixed;top:0;}
#sidebar.fixed_bottom>div{position:fixed;bottom:172px;}

jQuery(function ($) {
    $.fn.scrollBottom = function() { 
        return $(document).height() - this.scrollTop() - this.height(); 
    };

    var el = $('#sidebar'),
    pos = el.position().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= pos) {
            if ( $(this).scrollBottom() <= 172 ) { 
                el.removeClass('fixed');
                el.addClass('fixed_bottom');
            } else { 
                el.removeClass('fixed_bottom');
                el.addClass('fixed');
            }
        } else {
            el.removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is, on smaller resolutions, this makes the sidebar "jump" once you reach a certain position on the page. It stops it from overlapping the footer (which is the problem if you remove the `fixed_bottom` class) but doesn't look good.

What I'd like to do is this: user scrolls to the bottom of the page, the sidebar scrolls along with the content until it reaches say 20px above the top of my footer, at which point it stays there until the user scrolls back up.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe this should do what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/FDv2J/3/

```
#sidebar>div{ width: 100px; margin-top: 10px; position:fixed; left: 0; top: 0;}
```

---

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.scrollBottom = function() {
        return $(document).height() - this.scrollTop() - this.height();
    };

    var $el = $('#sidebar>div');
    var $window = $(window);

    $window.bind("scroll resize", function() {
        var gap = $window.height() - $el.height() - 10;
        var visibleFoot = 172 - $window.scrollBottom();
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop()

        if(scrollTop < 172 + 10){
            $el.css({
                top: (172 - scrollTop) + "px",
                bottom: "auto"
            });
        }else if (visibleFoot > gap) {
            $el.css({
                top: "auto",
                bottom: visibleFoot + "px"
            });
        } else {
            $el.css({
                top: 0,
                bottom: "auto"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I tried to break things up and name variables in such a way that it would be understandable.  Let me know if there's anything you're unsure of.  Notice that I added `resize` as well as scroll since it matters if the window changes size.

EDIT: Modified version using similar technique to the original to find the upper bound:

http://jsfiddle.net/FDv2J/4/

```js
$(function() {
  $.fn.scrollBottom = function() {
    return $(document).height() - this.scrollTop() - this.height();
  };

  var $el = $('#sidebar>div');
  var $window = $(window);
  var top = $el.parent().position().top;

  $window.bind("scroll resize", function() {
    var gap = $window.height() - $el.height() - 10;
    var visibleFoot = 172 - $window.scrollBottom();
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop()

    if (scrollTop < top + 10) {
      $el.css({
        top: (top - scrollTop) + "px",
        bottom: "auto"
      });
    } else if (visibleFoot > gap) {
      $el.css({
        top: "auto",
        bottom: visibleFoot + "px"
      });
    } else {
      $el.css({
        top: 0,
        bottom: "auto"
      });
    }
  }).scroll();
});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
#sidebar>div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
}
#stuff {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/100/100")
}
#footer,
#header {
  height: 172px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="header"></div>

<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="fixed">sidebar</div>
</div>

<div id="stuff">

</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>
```

Comment: That JSFiddle looks to be exactly what I'm after. I will test as soon as I'm home and let you know. Many thanks James.

Comment: Hi James. That works perfectly apart from one thing. In the original code, the "pos" var stops the sidebar from scrolling up above the header. http://dunc.seriouslyfish.com/Screenshot.png is what's happening at the moment. Could you implement the code to stop that from happening too?

Comment: Sorry for making you work for this answer James, but that hasn't really done the trick. With the original code the #sidebar appeared below the header, as per this copied page: http://dunc.seriouslyfish.com/test.htm. With yours the footer area works perfectly, but the header overlaps as per this copied page: http://dunc.seriouslyfish.com/test2.htm. I think the original code got round this by using "el.position.top()" to work out where the header div ended, so that the sidebar only scrolled once the scroller was past that point.

Comment: I was using the `172` just as an example of the height of your header.  That needed to be changed to the actual height.  This however should be a bit more dynamic and similar to your previous approach.  This way, no hardcoding for the.  You could similarly calculate the footer hgith instead of hardcoding that.  http://jsfiddle.net/FDv2J/4/