# jQuery - Have an element scroll with you down a page within a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code so far:

**HTML**

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="sidebar-wrapper"></div>
</div>
<div class="session-wrapper"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}
#content {
  height: 2000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

.sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px; /*depends on content*/
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.session-wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000000;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: #888;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(e){ 

var sidebar = jQuery('.sidebar-wrapper');
var sessions = jQuery('.session-wrapper');

var scrollTop     = jQuery(window).scrollTop(),
    elementOffset = sidebar.offset().top,
    distance      = (elementOffset - scrollTop),
    sessionOffset = sessions.offset().top;

var isPositionFixed = (sidebar.css('position') == 'fixed');

    if(distance < 60 && (sessionOffset - elementOffset) > 800 && !isPositionFixed) { 
            sidebar.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '100px', 'width': '350px'}); 
    }
    if((sessionOffset - elementOffset) < 800 && isPositionFixed || scrollTop > 1900) {
            sidebar.css({'position': 'static', 'top': '0px', 'width': '100%'}); 
    }

});
```

[SEE JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0czmb3Lg/)

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is that the grey box (`sidebar-wrapper`) scrolls down the page with you until it's about 20px away from `.sessions-wrapper`, once it is 20px away I am trying to get it to stay at this position until you scroll back up where it will scroll back up with you until it get's towards the top until it gets to it's original position. I guess I'm nearly there but I need some help getting this to work...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Cant you just add `position:fixed;` in your css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use various techniques to archive this. The new `position:sticky` property to achieve a similar result:

```
#sidebar-wrapper{
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: gray;
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/4hznD/

But I think that what you are looking is similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/FDv2J/4/ (extracted from: [jQuery scrolling DIV: stop scrolling when DIV reaches footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988697/jquery-scrolling-div-stop-scrolling-when-div-reaches-footer))

You could use a similar code (you should adapt it):

```
$(function() {
    $.fn.scrollBottom = function() {
        return $(document).height() - this.scrollTop() - this.height();
    };

    var $el = $('#sidebar>div');
    var $window = $(window);

    $window.bind("scroll resize", function() {
        var gap = $window.height() - $el.height() - 10;
        var visibleFoot = 172 - $window.scrollBottom();
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop()

        if(scrollTop < 172 + 10){
            $el.css({
                top: (172 - scrollTop) + "px",
                bottom: "auto"
            });
        }else if (visibleFoot > gap) {
            $el.css({
                top: "auto",
                bottom: visibleFoot + "px"
            });
        } else {
            $el.css({
                top: 0,
                bottom: "auto"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps!