# Scrolling sidebar pushes content down - never can get to footer

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a side bar that is following the users view

```
 $(function() {
        var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
        var topPadding = 125;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } else {
                $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 0
                });
            };
        });
    });
```

and it keeps pushing the content down the page, making it impossible to view the footer

here is the link to the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/5mbknwfk/2/

anyway to make the sidebar stop?

**EDIT:** Since it's in a column, it add's more space (margin-top) extending the column. Is there anyway to restrict it at the end of its column?

Comment: Images are broken in the fiddle, makes it hard to know if I'm seeing the layout correctly.

Comment: another thing that I noticed in the fiddle, no object with the ID of sidebar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery scrolling DIV: stop scrolling when DIV reaches footer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988697/jquery-scrolling-div-stop-scrolling-when-div-reaches-footer)

Comment: Not much of a duplicate. The code I used is from https://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/ and it moves the text via margin-top